# Windows 8 Application - Single Sign On In App - Not Domain joined

Tags: javascript, authentication, windows-8, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

I am building a Windows 8 application where I would capture and store credentials using the Password Vault.  I would like to then use them for all HTTPS requests to a specific domain.  This is easy enough for single requests but I would like it to be seamless.  I cannot use the enterprise authentication capability in the manifest because these machines are not joined to a domain.  I have looked at the Web Authentication broker but this seems to be directed towards using OAuth.

My question is, is there a way to either:

```
1) Enable Enterprise Authentication and white-list the domain to use
these credentials for (even though these machines are not domain joined)?

2) Use Web Authentication to somehow use
my credentials (that I capture during initial launch) for all HTTPS
requests without OAuth? 

3) If none of the above work, what is the
best way to use credentials that are in the Password Vault for all
HTTP requests to a specific domain, rather than pragmatically
submitting them with each request? (want this to be seamless so I
can write HTML without calling on this JavaScript function each
time.  Thanks!
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is possible in Windows 8. You need to submit credentials with each request using 
`WinJS.xhr()` or `XMLHttpRequest.open()`, or update your service to support OAuth or OpenID.